# An integral with variable in upper bound and need to find the function value

Tags: integration

so here is the question I had.

$$g(x)=\int_0^x \frac{u}{u^2+2} \, \mathrm du$$

and the question asked about the value of $g(1)$.

I understand the derivative of $g(x)$ is equal to $f(x)$, where $$f(u)=\frac{u}{u^2+2}$$ but why can't I use the function to get the original function's value? When I plug $x=1$, what I get is $$ \int_0^1 \frac{u}{u^2+2}\, \mathrm du$$ Why can't I just calculate this integral?

Comment: Good news: you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can!
$$g(1)=\int_0^1 \frac{u}{u^2+2} \, \mathrm du=\frac12\log(u^2+2)\bigg|_0^1=\frac12(\log 3-\log 2)=\frac12\log(3/2)$$